# Trouble binding jquery javascript click event to asp.net button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, button

Im using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(){

    alert('hello world');

});
```

});

And when I click the asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

It just doesnt fire. Anybody know why?

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(){

    alert('hello world');
});

});
```

And why you put .ClientID?? in the asp you dont put any class to the button

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sorry I figured it out it needs a pound sign before the selector!

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function(){

    alert('hello world');

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative here is to use a class so you can move your code externally, for example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Then your code can look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.btnSave').click(function() {
    alert('hello world');
  });
});
```

Which can be in an external `.js`, so your users download it once, not as part of the page each time.  Alternatively, a bit less efficient is to use the [attribute ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[id$=btnSave]').click(function() {
    alert('hello world');
  });
});
```

This will select all `<input>` elements that have an ID ending in `btnSave`.